# knockout binding inherited javascript objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have two types of activities like this:

```
function Activity(type, name) {
  this.Type = type
  this.Name = ko.observable(name)
}

function MeetingActivity(name, place) {
  Activity.call(this, 1500, name)
  this.Place = ko.observable(place)
}

function TeachingActivity(name, place, teacherId) {
  Activity.call(this, 1600, name)
  this.Place = ko.observable(place)
  this.TeacherId = ko.observable(teacherId)
}
```

and trying to bind activities of different types to some container like this:

```
Activity:
<select data-bind='value: ActivityTypeId'>
  <option value='1500'>Meeting</option>
  <option value='1600'>Teaching</option>
</select>
<div data-bind='if: ActivityTypeId()==1500'>
  <div data-bind='with: Activity'>
    <span data-bind='text:Name'></span>
    <span data-bind='text:Place'></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-bind='if: ActivityTypeId()==1600'>
  <div data-bind='with: Activity'>
    <span data-bind='text:Name'></span>
    <span data-bind='text:Place'></span>
    <span data-bind='text:TeacherId'></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I wrote [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvmf7e3q/2/) to get things done but with no luck, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, strange error: "Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return ActivityTypeId }"
Message: this.Activity is not a function" I double checked that this.Activity is defined in view model

Comment: How is `ActivityTypeId` defined?

Comment: Seems like a bug in the way Knockout handles `if` with `when` bindings. If you'll get rid of `with: Activity` and just use `text:Activity().Name/Place/TeacherId` it will be fine.

Comment: @haim770 I removed 'with' but same error, It seems the problem occures when removing TeacherId property while changing Activity variable from Teaching to Meeting,

Comment: @RoyJ please take a look to the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xvmf7e3q/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your [original fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvmf7e3q/2/) is that you updated `Activity` to contain a new type, and the display changes to display that type, but there is going to be some time when the type contained and the type expected to display are not the same.

To ensure that there are no synchronization problems, you should test on `Activity.Type` (which should be an observable). Also, instead of making `Activity` an observable and subscribing to change its value, just make it a computed.

```js
function Activity(type, name) {
  this.Type = ko.observable(type)
  this.Name = ko.observable(name)
}

function MeetingActivity(name, place) {
  Activity.call(this, 1500, name)
  this.Place = ko.observable(place)
}

function TeachingActivity(name, place, teacherId) {
  Activity.call(this, 1600, name)
  this.Place = ko.observable(place)
  this.TeacherId = ko.observable(teacherId)
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this
  self.ActivityTypeId = ko.observable(1500);
  self.Activity = ko.computed(
    function() {
      var typeId = +self.ActivityTypeId();

      if (typeId == 1500) return new MeetingActivity('meeting 1', 'g12');
      else if (typeId == 1600) return new TeachingActivity('meeting 2', 'g13', 155);
      else console.warn('Type ID:', typeId);
    });
}
var VM = null
$(document).ready(function() {
  VM = new ViewModel()
  ko.applyBindings(VM)
  console.log(VM)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Activity:
<select data-bind='value: ActivityTypeId'>
  <option value='1500'>Meeting</option>
  <option value='1600'>Teaching</option>
</select>
<div data-bind="with: Activity">
  <div data-bind='if: Type()==1500'>
    <span data-bind='text:Name'></span>
    <span data-bind='text:Place'></span>
  </div>

  <div data-bind='if: Type()==1600'>
    <span data-bind='text:Name'></span>
    <span data-bind='text:Place'></span>
    <span data-bind='text:TeacherId'></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roy J, you hit the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error from the fiddle you provided is from the `subscribe` method of `ActivityTypeId`. Remember that when creating a `function`, the `this` is overwritten with the current scope of the function, so `Activity` is now lost in your current `this`.

```
function ViewModel() {
  this.ActivityTypeId = ko.observable(1500);
  this.Activity = ko.observable(new MeetingActivity('meeting 1', 'g12', 155))

  this.ActivityTypeId.subscribe(function(typeId) {
    if (typeId == 1500) this.Activity(new MeetingActivity('meeting 1', 'g12'))
    else if (typeId == 1600) this.Activity(new TeachingActivity('meeting 2', 'g13', 155))
  })
}
```

To fix it, you can assign this to another variable and access the activity by it. Like:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this; //this is what i meant in assigning in another variable
  this.ActivityTypeId = ko.observable(1500);
  this.Activity = ko.observable(new MeetingActivity('meeting 1', 'g12', 155))

  this.ActivityTypeId.subscribe(function(typeId) {
    if (typeId == 1500) self.Activity(new MeetingActivity('meeting 1', 'g12')) //use self on accessing Activity
    else if (typeId == 1600) self.Activity(new TeachingActivity('meeting 2', 'g13', 155)) //use self on accessing Activity
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the primary error that i'm focusing to solve is when changing activity from  'teaching' to 'meeting'.
error is 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return TeacherId }"
Message: TeacherId is not defined'